# How to replace chars in a string

Tags: string, assembly, x86

If I have a `string` like 'aabbcc' how can I change the 2nd and 4th `char` to another `char`?

EDIT: I'm using NASM on Windows, and yes, this is part of a big homework assignment.

Comment: What assembler and what processor? What have you tried? Is this homework?

Comment: I'm using NASM on Windows, and yes this is part of a big homework assignment. I've just started this course, so haven't tried anything yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute with 'd':

```
lea eax, addr string ( or mov eax, string)
mov byte ptr [eax+1], 64h
mov byte ptr [eax+3], 64h
```

Answer (score -4):

In Java and many other languages, you can't.  Strings are immutable objects.   In
many other languages you shouldn't.  Strings you did not create a likely to be literals,
and changing them changes the string for some indefinite value of "everyone".

Comment: what makes you think the OP's question is about Java?